# joomla to wordpress migration and 404 errors issues

Tags: url-rewriting, htaccess

I had migrated my website from Joomla to WordPress with "FG Joomla to WordPress premium"

the problem is that I have more than 2900 posts in my website they all are now imported in WordPress version but images in my posts are linked like this:

```
example.com/postname/articles/image.jpg
```

but in WordPress images should be like :

```
example.com/wp-content/year/month/image.jpg
```

now I all my 2900 posts images are broken and not shown.

I decided to redirect it but I don't know how to that cause it's variable post names !!

Comment: "wordpress to joomla" or "Joomla to WordPress"? Is `articles` a fixed string?

Comment: sorry about the mistake in the title it's "Joomla to WordPress" 
yes, "articles" is fixed but posts titles are variable.

Comment: Please contact the developers of FG Joomla to WordPress premium for support as third party plugins and themes are out of scope for this site.

Comment: "I don't know how to that cause it's variable post names" - the problem here isn't the "variable postnames", but the presumably _variable_ `year` and `month` in the target URL. I assume they are not literal strings, so where are these expected to come from?